# Rails, naming convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, naming-conventions

What is the convention for naming a has_many through table/model if I have a model called events and one called users?

Is it events_users for the table? If so I get a problem with naming the Model, because rails doesn't seem to like EventUser, nor does it seem to like EventsUser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Try naming your table `events_users`. By default, the two involved tables in a `has_many through` or a `has_and_belongs_to_many` are pluralized and ordered alphabetically.

You only need a model for the association if you plan on using it. If so, name it logically, and tell ActiveRecord the table name is `events_users`.

Answer (score 0):

With has_many :through, you name it whatever you want - Rails doesn't have a problem at all... TABLE names are always fully plural (userS, eventS, usersS_eventS), and models are always singular (user, event, user_event)

Just use the generator:

```
 rails g model something:data_type another_thing:data_type
```